# logged in github session in electron

Tags: session, cookies, electron

Is there any way i could inject a logged in github session in a `electron` window?

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
})
win.loadURL('https://www.github.com')
```

Comment: As the [docs for BrowserWindow](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/) don't contain anything targeting this, I think it is not possible...

Comment: You want logged in session only or perhaps you can open homepage and log in through electron?

Comment: Log in through electron is no problem. I was wandering if i could inject the right cookies and get directly logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Electron has a [Cookies API](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/cookies/) that you can use to do just this. So for example you would have something like the following, and just set all the cookies you need to. (example taken from documentation)

```js
const cookie = {
                   url: 'http://www.github.com',
                   name: 'dummy_name',
                   value: 'dummy'
               }

session.defaultSession.cookies.set(cookie, (error) => {
    if (error) console.error(error)
})
```

Also, when writing a feature such as this make sure you are [being secure and responsible](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/security/). Ensure this does not open a vulnerability for users and that user privacy is being respected.

Comment: If i look in chrome dev tools i see cookies in this form: https://s4.postimg.org/5zdukcoct/cookie.jpg , but if i do  `session.defaultSession.cookies.get({url:'https://www.github.com'} ,(err, cookies) => console.log(cookies))` i get another type of object. So what i'm trying to say is could you provide a more close to reality example?

Comment: To be clear, you mean dev tools in an electron window, correct? Or are you logged in on **Chrome** and viewing the cookies **in Chrome**? And could you provide what response that code gives you?

Comment: Yes, i logged to github with Chrome and those are the cookies for my account. And the response that code gives is this: https://image.ibb.co/griDza/cookir.jpg

Comment: You need to use the cookie values from chrome and use the code I posted to set in electron the cookies from Chrome. This is *technically* session hijacking, but since it is your own session there's no issue.